# jQuery + jQuery mobile load script twice when script tag is emebedded in body

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

i have found a strange behavior when i was learning jQuery Mobile. below is my test code. the firebug shows the "test.js" was loaded twice if i put the script tag in body(even the "test.js" is empty). is this a bug or we could not put script tag in body when we are using jquery mobile?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>test</title>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, put all your javascript in the head. This solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've never ran into such issues, but try adding the script tag AFTER the  element (but before the ) one), or even better, load it dymically after the pagecreate event.